# C++ printing pointer doesn't acknowledge showbase

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I've noticed a discrepancy in the way we print pointers. gcc by default is adding 0x prefix to hex output of pointer, and Microsoft's compiler doesn't do that. showbase/noshowbase doesn't affect either of them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
void * n = (void *)1;
cout << noshowbase << hex << n << dec << endl;
// output (g++ (GCC) 4.7.2, 5.4.0): 0x1
// output (VS 2010, 2013): 00000001

n = (void *)10;
cout << noshowbase << hex << n << dec << endl;
// output (g++ (GCC) 4.7.2, 5.4.0): 0xa
// output (VS 2010, 2013): 0000000A

n = (void *)0;
cout << noshowbase << hex << n << dec << endl;
// output (g++ (GCC) 4.7.2, 5.4.0): 0
// output (VS 2010, 2013): 00000000

return 0;
}
```

I assume this is implementation defined behavior and not a bug, but is there a way to stop any compiler from prepending the 0x? We are already prepending the 0x on our own but in gcc it comes out like 0x0xABCD.

I'm sure I could do something like `ifdef __GNUC___ ....` but I wonder if I'm missing something more obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose that you cast to `intptr` and treat the input as a normal integer.
Your I/O manipulators should then work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void * n = (void *)1;
    cout << noshowbase << hex << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(n) << dec << endl;

    n = (void *)10;
    cout << noshowbase << hex << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(n) << dec << endl;

    n = (void *)0;
    cout << noshowbase << hex << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(n) << dec << endl;
}

// 1
// a
// 0
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/568d0108d5c5c7e6))

At first I was a little surprised by your question (more specifically, by these implementations' behaviour), but the more I think about it the more it makes sense. Pointers are not numbers*, and there's really no better authority on how to render them than the implementation.

<sub>* I'm serious! Although, funnily enough, for implementation/historical reasons, the standard calls a `const void*` "numeric" in this context, using the `num_put` locale stuff for formatted output, ultimately deferring to `printf` in `[facet.num.put.virtuals]`. The standard states that the formatting specifier `%p` should be used but, since the result of `%p` is implementation-defined, you could really get just about anything with your current code.</sub>